# Multiple inner join and left join in same query sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables called Message,File and Document.

**Message** columns - Pid,MessageId,MName,MContent
**File** columns - FileId,MessageId,Size, type
**Documen**t columns - FileId, DocumentPath, DocumentName

Scenario:

Single message can have multiple files or no files. I need to select 
Mname,Mcontent,FileId,DocumentName and display it to UI in table format.

```
select 
       M.Mname as Name,Mcontent,D.FileId,D.DocumentName  
       FROM Message M 
       inner Join File F
       ON F.MessageID=M.MessageID
       inner join document D
       ON D.fileId=f.fileId     
       WHERE M.PID='6AE3B832'
```

But am not getting expected result. Pid will always have more than 1 messageID.

Can anyone suggest to achieve the result.

Expected result something like below,

```html
<table border="1">
  <th>Mname</th>
  <th>Mcontent</th>
  <th>Fileid</th>
  <th>Documentname</th>
  <tr>
  <td>1st message</td>
    <td>1st mesage content</td>
    <td>001</td>
    <td>message.pdf</td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>1st message</td>
    <td>1st mesage content</td>
    <td>002</td>
    <td>userManual.doc</td>    
  </tr>
   <tr>
  <td>2nd message</td>
    <td>2nd mesage content</td>
    <td>null</td>
    <td>null</td>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>3rd message</td>
    <td>3rd mesage content</td>
    <td>003</td>
    <td>policy.xlsx</td>    
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: And what result are you expecting?

Comment: @Giorgi i have edited expected result

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
   M.Mname as Name,Mcontent,D.FileId,D.DocumentName  
FROM Message M 
   LEFT JOIN File F
     ON F.MessageID=M.MessageID
   LEFT JOIN document D
     ON D.fileId=f.fileId     
WHERE M.PID='6AE3B832'
```

If you use an inner join both tables must have a matching record. A left join only requires the table Message to have a record.